# MSSQL: To take all results to the first row with multi-column

Tags: sql-server

I'm new on the SQL. I have a problem with getting the result. I have to send all results to the first row. How can I fix it?

**Here is an image of the problem:**

[image]

```
SELECT
 case when anaForm.txtQ1='Kesinlikle Katılıyorum' then count(anaForm.txtQ1) end [YES100]
,case when anaForm.txtQ1='Katılıyorum' then count(anaForm.txtQ1) end as [YES75]
,case when anaForm.txtQ1='Benim için bir şey değişmedi' then count(anaForm.txtQ1) end as [NEITHER0]
,case when anaForm.txtQ1='Katılmıyorum' then count(anaForm.txtQ1) end as [NO100]
from E_prj_pazarlama_fuar_Anket_Form anaForm 
inner join DOCUMENTS D ON anaForm.ID = D.ID 
inner join FLOWDOCUMENTS FD ON anaForm.ID = FD.FILEPROFILEID
inner join LIVEFLOWS L ON FD.PROCESSID = L.ID 
inner join FLOWSTATUSES FS on FS.VERSION=L.FLOWVERSION and fs.STATUS=l.STATUS and fs.PROCESS='prj_pazarlama_fuar_Anket'
WHERE L.DELETED=0 AND D.DELETED=0 
AND L.FINISHED = 1 AND L.FLOWSTEP>1 
Group by  anaForm.txtQ1
```

Comment: `SUM(CASE)` is what you are looking for. May want to put an `ELSE 0` in your `CASE` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you are looking for.

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT
 SUM(case when anaForm.txtQ1='Kesinlikle Katılıyorum' then 1 
 ELSE 0 end) [YES100]
,SUM(case when anaForm.txtQ1='Katılıyorum' then 1 ELSE 0 end ) as [YES75]
,SUM(case when anaForm.txtQ1='Benim için bir şey değişmedi' then 1 ELSE 0 end) as [NEITHER0]
,SUM(case when anaForm.txtQ1='Katılmıyorum' then 1 ELSE 0 end) as [NO100]
from E_prj_pazarlama_fuar_Anket_Form anaForm 
inner join DOCUMENTS D ON anaForm.ID = D.ID 
inner join FLOWDOCUMENTS FD ON anaForm.ID = FD.FILEPROFILEID
inner join LIVEFLOWS L ON FD.PROCESSID = L.ID 
inner join FLOWSTATUSES FS on FS.VERSION=L.FLOWVERSION and fs.STATUS=l.STATUS and fs.PROCESS='prj_pazarlama_fuar_Anket'
WHERE L.DELETED=0 AND D.DELETED=0 
AND L.FINISHED = 1 AND L.FLOWSTEP>1 
-- Group by  anaForm.txtQ1 *** This is giving you 3 rows. Comment this out and try
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. But result: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Ah... Remove `Count(anaForm.txtQ1)` and put `1` in.

Comment: @WEI_DBA, case staments should look like this: `SUM( case when anaForm.txtQ1 ='Katılıyorum' then 1 ELSE 0 end ) as [YES75]`

Comment: Agreed. I'll update. Should have edited it after @AhmetKeskin first comment. My bad.

Comment: Updated. Thank you!

Comment: Comment out the `Group by anaForm.txtQ1`

Comment: Thank you very much. It Works. :) [Screen View](https://preview.ibb.co/fi5qYG/Screen_Shot_2017_11_08_at_17_14_47.png)

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked. Mark as answered please. :-)